# Defining a 2-d numpy array from values in 3-d numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have a 3-D numpy array representing a model domain of 39 layers, 279 rows, 153 columns. The values in the array are either 0 or 1 and signify if the cell in the domain is inactive or active, respectively. I am trying to create a 2-D array of shape 279 rows and 153 columns where the array values equal the layer number for the uppermost active layer in the grid. Essentially, at each row, col location I want to loop through the layers to find the first one that is a 1 and not a 0 and then put that layer number in the 2-D array at that row, col location. For example:

If a four layer (layers 0-3) array looks like this:

```
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]],
   
       [[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

The 2-D array should look like this:

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]],
```

If the row-col location is not active (not equal to 1) in any layer , the value in the resulting array should be 0 (like at 1,1), the same as if it were active in layer 0.

I have tried modifying a couple of solutions where the z-axis values are summed, or averaged, but can't seem to figure out how to get exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You could do a cumulative sum on the layers, and then count the zeros. This way would differentiate between a slice that is all 0s, and one that has no zeros, which your answer doesn't seem to differentiate: `(x.cumsum(axis=0) == 0).sum(axis=0)`, to get the zero slices to be 0 as well you can add `% x.shape[0]` at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `numpy.argmax`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
print(np.argmax(a,0))

 
array([[0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

This works because argmax returns the [first max value](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax) when searching over the defined axis (in this case the 0th axis).